# What should I back up before reinstalling new Ubuntu LTS? (8.04 > 10.04)

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-8.04, reinstall

A work server is in need of upgrading, im hoping to move it from 8.04 LTS to 10.04 LTS (Can't move to 12.04 unfortunately as its not provided by our VPS provider)

I have backed up the following.

- /home & website files
- All MySQL dbs
- Apache config
- Postfix config
- Hostname data
- Crontab files

With the above i reckon I can set up my new server to function in the same manner as the old one fairly quickly, however im wondering if theres anything obvious I have missed which could cause me some problems?

First time doing this with a production server, so im a bit nervous.....eeek!

Thanks.

Comment: What does your server do? What applications does it run? Instead of upgrade why not install a 2nd server, make sure it's running as desired and then decommission the old one?

Comment: It hosts a few websites, sends out html emails to mailing lists and various cron jobs, nothing to complicated. Unfortunately an additional server is not really an option as I'm not in charge of covering the costs of an additional server and this current one is on a yearly contract.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to use [do-release-upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)? Generally, this is the way to upgrade releases. It does an in-place upgrade that is quite reliable.

If there is some reason you can't do this, I'd suggest backing up all of /etc/ and /var/.

Comment: With our current provider, i wasn't sure if this was available. I'll give it a bash and see if i can avoid the complete reinstall.